# Absolute positioning a block element alignes it with it's sibling element

Tags: css, html, css-position

I got an unexpected behavior when trying to absolute position an h3(or any other block element) element inside header. Since absolute positioning is made relative to the first non-static parent element, the h3 element should have aligned at the top of the window relative to the container. But for some reason it aligns with it's sibling nav element. Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sometitle</title>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:lightgray;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#main-header {
    display:block;
}

#main-header #logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#main-header #main-nav {
    display:block;
    background:gray;
    margin:5em 6em;
}

#main-header #main-nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

#main-header #main-nav .main-nav-link {
    display:inline-block;
}

#main-header #main-nav .main-nav-link a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.8em 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font:bold 1em arial;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="main-header">
        <h3 id="logo">Some logo</h3>

        <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav1</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav2</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav3</a></li>     
            </ul>       
        </nav>  
    </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Advice - Make it a `js Fiddle`. Let me convert and take a look. See? [Not so hard](http://jsfiddle.net/aLSXn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#main-header #main-nav {
    margin:5em 6em;
}
```

**There's your problem:**

```
<header id="main-header">
    <h3 id="logo">Some logo</h3>

    <nav id="main-nav">
        <ul>...
```

Your `H3` is part of `main-header` with crazy `margins`.

**Try something like this instead:**

#### See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aLSXn/3/

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <header id="main-header">
        <h3 id="logo">Some logo</h3>
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav1</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav2</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav-link"><a href="#">Nav3</a></li>     
            </ul>       
        </nav>  
    </header>
</div
```

#### CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    background:lightgray;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
}

#main-header {
    display:block;
}

#logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#main-nav {
    display:block;
    background:gray;
    margin:5em 6em;
}

#main-nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

#main-nav .main-nav-link {
    display:inline-block;
}

#main-nav .main-nav-link a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.8em 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font:bold 1em arial;
}
```

#### See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aLSXn/3/

Comment: Thanks, that works. But it didn't answer my original question. Why doesn't h3 postition itself absolutely relative to container, when container is positioned relative, but instead alignes with it's sibling nav element?

Comment: Because you're defining the **parent** element with **position:relative** which makes it take the `em` into account. `static` is the only `position css property` that actually renders the `DOM` without manipulating it. Keep in mind, you set **ultimate** parent containers `html, body{position:relative;}`